# Storing result of linq in keyvaluepair with key and value after spliting the String using comma seperator

Tags: c#, linq

I am not able to get the result what i am required
Please go through this.

I am calling liq query which will give me result like

```
"99,85,34,20,1,0.5" as key
"5000199,5000185,5000134,5000120,5000101,5000005"
```

I want this to be like key and value format after spliting them...Like

```
key            value
99             5000199
85             5000185
```

in list like key should be 99 and value for this should be 5000199
second key should be 85 and value for this should be 5000185

Query i am using is

```
var pp = (from a in dc.MediaTypeMasters 
         where a.MediaTypeID == 153 && 
               a.ContentTypeForBilling == "valuepack" 
        select new KeyValuePair<String, String>
                               (a.PartialPricePoints, a.ContentTypeID))
               .ToList();
```

Like this.

Comment: Could you show us the exact LINQ query you're doing ?

Comment: What types are a.PartialPricePoints and a.ContentTypeId ?

Comment: @TommyGrovnes String both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Zip` method from LINQ:

```
var keys = "99,85,34,20,1,0.5";
var values = "5000199,5000185,5000134,5000120,5000101,5000005";

var results = keys.Split(',').Zip(values.Split(','), (k, v) => 
                        new KeyValuePair<int, int>(int.Parse(k), int.Parse(v)));
```

You can then create `Dicrionary<int, int>` as well:

```
var dict = results.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: +1 The code is fine, the only problem is the last key "0.5" that throws in the `int.Parse`.

Comment: Getting Input string was not in a correct format. Should be KeyValuePair<string, string> :)

Comment: The following change fixes it: new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k,v)));

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want key-value pairs according to their index in two collections?

```
string[] first = str1.Split(',');
string[] second= str2.Split(',');
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs = first
    .Select((s, i) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s, second.ElementAtOrDefault(i)));
```

Note that `Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault` returns `null` if the second collection doesn't contain as many items as the `first`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string key = "99,85,34,20,1,0.5";
    string val = "5000199,5000185,5000134,5000120,5000101,5000005";

    var keyArr = key.Split(',');
    var valArr = val.Split(',');
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < keyArr.Length; i++)
    {
        dictionary.Add(keyArr[i], valArr[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make things simple.

Use

```
var pp = (from a in dc.MediaTypeMasters where a.MediaTypeID == 153 && a.ContentTypeForBilling == "valuepack" a).ToList();
```

Then you can do

```
var dictionary = pp.ToDictionary(p => p.PartialPricePoints);
```